# extend_lock vs set_lock

Tags: lockable-currency

Can someone explain the difference between `set_lock` and `extend_lock`?

From my reading of the documentation on both, I figure that `extend_lock` should be called when we want to impose more locks on an already locked account, ie, if my pallet has already called `set_lock` on `Alice`, and she makes another call to the same pallet, rather than creating a new lock, I `extend_lock`.

Question : for a particular `LockIdentifier` does calling `extend_lock` add to the amount already locked and does `set_lock` reset the lock with a new amount with which it was called? Would that imply that `extend_lock` increases the number of `locks` on an account, whereas `set_lock` keeps the number of `locks` constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `set_lock` *replaces* any previous lock of the given identifier with the new lock. The previous amount which is locked under the given identifier is completely disregarded.
- `extend_lock` does not replace any existing lock of the given identifier, but rather leaves the final amount locked as the *maximum* of the previous amount and the new amount.

Basically, if you do not want to *reduce* the amount that is locked with the given identifier, use `extend_lock`. If do want to allow the possibility of the amount locked with the given identifier to reduce, use `set_lock`.

In both cases, a new lock is created if there was no previous lock with the given identifier in place. Similarly no new locks are created if there was.